# Kiosk, Rom + Launcher, need a little guidance

Tags: gps, rom, nfc, kiosk-mode

I am currently developing a software for use in the Home health industry, which handles Verifying an aid is actually administering care (EVV). This works with GPS and the read of a fixed NFC chip. i have the application itself developed using Phonegap and Nodejs and it works well, but id like to kiosk this application on a 4g enabled device.

Now i know to kiosk, i need a launcher not a custom ROM to do this, which isn't an issue, but i do not want the aides to be able to access the drawer or settings menus, or really any function of the phone other than the application itself. This is problematic if NFC or GPS is not on at boot. do i need to customize the ROM for these 2 functions to be permanently forced to remain on? or is there a way i can do this in the launcher app itself?

Thanks in advance

Comment: bump? anyone? still hoping for an answer